# Python - Ipywidgets - SelectMultiple - Create a Select ALL option

Tags: python, ipywidgets, selectall

I currently am using the selectmultiple widget in ipywidgets and I'm looking for a better solution. I have 200+ countries that a user can select from and sometimes they want to SELECT ALL. Using this widget they need to click on each and every country and this is very time consuming. Does anyone have another suggestion or option that I can try. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
widgets.SelectMultiple(
options=['Afghanistan', 
          'Aland Islands',
          'Albania'
          'Algeria',
        #Code continues for 249 countries
         ],
value=['Afghanistan'],
#rows=10,
description='Countries',
disabled=False
 )
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use CMD+A in Mac to select all in the usual way, imagine CTRL+A will work for Windows too.

But if you need a widget, how about a button next to it that performs the same action?

```py
import ipywidgets as widgets
sel = widgets.SelectMultiple(
options=['Afghanistan', 
          'Aland Islands',
          'Albania',
          'Algeria',
        #Code continues for 249 countries
         ],
value=['Afghanistan'],
#rows=10,
description='Countries',
disabled=False
 )


but = widgets.Button(description = 'Select all')

def select_all(*args):
    sel.value = sel.options

but.on_click(select_all)

display(sel)
display(but)
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me - including the ctrl-a or command-a to select all in the ui, which is a serious pain.  

SelectMultiple can use a list of tuples, with ("string to display", valueOutputIfSelected) pairs. If you're using that, you need more magic. In your function above, sel.options would have to be the list of all the values, not all the name/value tuples. I did this:

sel.value = tuple([outputvalue[1] for outputvalue in sel.options])

Uses a list comprehension to get all the output values, and converts them into a big tuple like the output would be, e.g. (value1, value2, ...)

Answer (score 0):

I have handled this by adding an 'ALL' option at the top of the list:

```py
import ipywidgets as widgets
sel = widgets.SelectMultiple(
options=['ALL',
          'Afghanistan', 
          'Aland Islands',
          'Albania',
          'Algeria',
        #Code continues for 249 countries
         ],
value=['ALL'],
#rows=10,
description='Countries',
disabled=False
 )
```

This way the they will get all if they want it by default or they can choose a smaller number of items as usual.

regards